# Fill datagridview from listbox or settings collection

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, listbox

There are listbox (data connected with settings) and datagridview in my form. I am trying to fill 0th column in datagridview from listbox. Can not find the solution on web, so I've tried this one :

```
            For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = ListBox1.Items

        Next
```

And the result is just one item in column 0 : "System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection"

Obviously that has something to do with setting (where data from listbox is saved) and I don't know how to fix it.

P.S. That code above also deletes items from listbox!?

EDIT :

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Visible = False
    For Each item As String In My.Settings.Setting
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(("BNK"), "Bank")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(("ZR"), "2410")
        DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 55
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft

        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Dim dr As New DataGridViewRow
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr)
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = ListBox1.Items(i)
            DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

and

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If Button3.Text = "Add a bank" Then
        TextBox1.Visible = True
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Button3.Text = "Confirm"
    ElseIf Button3.Text = "Confirm" Then

        TextBox1.Visible = False
        Button3.Text = "Add a bank"
        Dim newURL As String = TextBox1.Text.ToString

        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text.ToString) 'add to ListBox1
        My.Settings.Setting.Add(TextBox1.Text.ToString) 'add to My.Settings.favList


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you are trying to add ALL the LB items to a single cell

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. it works

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    dim cmd as SqlCommand("Select col1 from tblname",conn)
    dim da as new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    dim ds as new dataset
    da.fill(ds)
    Listbox1.datasource=ds
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "col1"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "col1"
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim dr As New DataGridViewRow
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr)
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = ListBox1.Items(i)
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
dim cmd as new SqlCommand("insert into tblname values('" & textbox1.Text & "')",conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim dr As New DataGridViewRow
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr)
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = ListBox1.Items(i)
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it does, but it adds an extra row to datagridview on load. Also I am using that code after adding new item so every new item adds another row to datagridview.

Comment: When I add 10 items in listbox, I'll get 10 items in a datagridview and 10 empty rows.

Comment: i have edited the answer...if it helps upvote and mark it as solution

Comment: Starting with the empty listbox : adding first item in LB add 1 row with that value to DGV, adding second item to LB adds 2 rows (one with 2nd item second row is empty), third add 3 rows (one with item value and two blank rows) and so on.

Comment: so you are adding each listbox item as well gridview cell value at a same time. is it?

Comment: I've removed that code from add item to listbox (button event). Your code is only in form_load. I add an item to listbox (then I close app/start it again), add second item (close/load)...so that I can test it and that multiplication of row is happening.

Comment: you have to give that for loop on both form_load as well in the button click

Comment: I did that and I have the same prob. I've edited original post to add FormLoad and button click code
Your code was also in button event but I removed it 'cause of the problem I have (row multiplication)

Comment: there is one possibility to store them into database and fetching them back on grid

Comment: I know, but I was hoping to avoid having extra files like database file for this application.

Answer (score 0):

This Will Do The Trick...

```
For Count = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count -1 
   DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(Count).Value = ListBox1.Items(Count)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = ListBox1.Items(i)

    Next
```

Comment: Works the first time, after app is loaded for the second time I get this error : Index was out of range. Must be non...
Also every item in listbox, except the first one is deleted.
Items are stored in settings.

Comment: does your grid has any rows by static(at design)?

Comment: No. It is an empty datagridview. The columns (two) are created in Form_load.
BTW. I forgot to say that datagridview is populated (using your code) with that one remaining item after I click on continue (Error screen).

Comment: that is the problem. since you dont have any row at your grid, first you have to create a row inside the for loop. following that you can assign the value for first cell.